# Jquery & Ajax Pagination callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, pagination

I am looking for an advice. This doesn't work:

`https://jsfiddle.net/ss9hn99d/`

```
<script id="moo" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>Simons Easy Ajax Pagination</title>

<body>
<h1>Simons Easy Ajax Pagination (jQuery)</h1>

<div id="pagination_controls">
<div id="pagination_control_wrapper">
</div>
</div>
<div id="pagination_container">
<div id="pagination_content_wrapper">
</div>
</div>

<div class="points">

<strong>Features</strong>
<ul>
<li>Ajaxian Pagination</li>
<li>Back &amp; Forward button support</li>
<li>URL ajax navigation <a href="pagination_jquery.php#p=4" rel="nofollow">Go To page 4</a></li>
<li>JavaScript ajax navigation whithin class "this.pLoad('3');" loads page 3</li>
<li>Left to Right, or Right to Left animated slide</li>
</ul>

<strong>To Do</strong>
<ul>
<li>Cache with on/off switch</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

but it should work like:

http://www.aplusdesign.com.au/misc/pagination/pagination_jquery.php#p=1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please indent your code, it will be easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <script id="moo" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <title>Simons Easy Ajax Pagination</title>

 <body>
  <h1>Simons Easy Ajax Pagination (jQuery)</h1>

   <div id="pagination_controls">
    <div id="pagination_control_wrapper">
    </div>
   </div>
     <div id="pagination_container">
      <div id="pagination_content_wrapper">
      </div>
     </div>

       <div class="points">

        <strong>Features</strong>
         <ul>
          <li>Ajaxian Pagination</li>
          <li>Back &amp; Forward button support</li>
          <li>URL ajax navigation <a href="pagination_jquery.php#p=4" rel="nofollow">Go To page 4</a></li>
          <li>JavaScript ajax navigation whithin class "this.pLoad('3');" loads page 3</li>
          <li>Left to Right, or Right to Left animated slide</li>
         </ul>

        <strong>To Do</strong>
         <ul>
          <li>Cache with on/off switch</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please add some feedback to your answer